Create age group column from birthday
I'm trying to create an age calculation column from a birthdate, and then create an age-group column based on the age column.  I've done some searching, but all the results I can find are structured differently enough that I'm not sure I'm even approaching this in the correct way.
The query is this:
select unique ccy.bi_cust_nbr
--, ccy.bi_acct
, ccm.bi_cust_stat_cd
, p.bi_sort_name
, sl.bi_addr1
, p.bi_birth_dt
, sl.bi_board_dist_cd
--, sl.bi_srv_map_loc
, trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) as age1
, (case
    when age1 between 18 and 25 then '18-24'
    when age1 between 25 and 46 then '25-45'
    when age1 between 46 and 66 then '46-65'
    when age1 between 66 and 130 then '65+'
  END) as Age_Group
from cc_ye_stat ccy
left join cc_master ccm on ccm.bi_cust_nbr=ccy.bi_cust_nbr
left join bi_personal p on p.bi_cust_nbr = ccy.bi_cust_nbr
left join bi_srv_loc sl on sl.bi_srv_loc_nbr=ccy.bi_srv_loc_nbr
where ccy.bi_srv_stat_cd in (1,3,6,7)
and p.bi_birth_dt > '01-JAN-1902'
--and ccy.bi_cust_nbr = 95051
and p.bi_birth_dt is not null
order by Age_Group desc

And the results just need to have a new column with one of the CASE results in them (18-24, etc.).  I've got the age column working, but when I try to add the CASE section to make a new column for the age group I'm getting this error:
"ORA-00904: "AGE1": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 32 Column: 10" 

which points to the last of the WHEN clauses in the CASE section.

You cannot reference your age1 alias in the case expression of the same select statement. Just replace age1 in your case expression with your method for calculating age. Also, between is inclusive, so adjust your ranges to correctly reflect what you want to include in each age band.

Tip of today: Switch to SELECT DISTINCT. ISO/ANSI SQL and universal SQL - i.e. portable and everybody understand it.

Move the p conditions from WHERE to ON to get true LEFT JOIN result. As it is now, you get regular INNER JOIN result.

And p.bi_birth_dt is not null is redundant, only non-null values can satisfy p.bi_birth_dt > '01-JAN-1902'.

Try this:
select unique ccy.bi_cust_nbr
--, ccy.bi_acct
, ccm.bi_cust_stat_cd
, p.bi_sort_name
, sl.bi_addr1
, p.bi_birth_dt
, sl.bi_board_dist_cd
--, sl.bi_srv_map_loc
, trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) as age1
, (case
    when trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) between 18 and 25 then '18-24'
    when trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) between 25 and 46 then '25-45'
    when trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) between 46 and 66 then '46-65'
    when trunc(months_between(sysdate,p.bi_birth_dt)/12) between 66 and 130 then '65+'
  END) as Age_Group
from cc_ye_stat ccy
left join cc_master ccm on ccm.bi_cust_nbr=ccy.bi_cust_nbr
left join bi_personal p on p.bi_cust_nbr = ccy.bi_cust_nbr
left join bi_srv_loc sl on sl.bi_srv_loc_nbr=ccy.bi_srv_loc_nbr
where ccy.bi_srv_stat_cd in (1,3,6,7)
and p.bi_birth_dt > '01-JAN-1902'
--and ccy.bi_cust_nbr = 95051
and p.bi_birth_dt is not null
order by 8 desc


ORDER BY ordinal position is a poor advice. Keep the column alias.

That did it, thank you!
